# Autofac Build() throws exception on latest Xamarin iOS when Linker configured to Link All

Tags: ios, xamarin, linker, autofac

After upgrading to Visual Studio 16.3.0 (Visual Studio for Mac 8.3.1805) Autofac throwns an exeception when doing `builder.Build()` in a project that previously worked:

> The type 'Autofac.Features.Indexed.KeyedServiceIndex'2' does not
>   implement the interface 'Autofac.Features.Indexed.IIndex'2'

With this release of Visual Studio (and maybe earlier versions too), iOS is compiled using Mono 6.4.0.198 and I suspected that this might be what is introducing the braking change. Alternatively the linker behaves differently with the latest tool-chain. All I can say is that this used to work and now it doesn't.

Following these guidelines is not sufficient: [Cross-Platform and Native Applications](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/cross-platform-apps.html#xamarin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work around the issue, first make sure that Autofac is installed both in the iOS project, Android and the .NET Standard shared project, then choose one of these two options:

1. Set the linker to `Don't link` or `Link Framework SDK's Only`
2. Or, you can; add `--linkskip=Autofac` (case sensitive!) to the `Additional mtouch arguments` in `iOS Build` found in the iOS project properties.
3. Or, you can; create a [Custom Linker Configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker), which I btw think is the best option if you need linking. It's a little bit more work, but when using a `Linker Description file` the compiler will give you usable feedback when you build, if you've made a mistake like misspelling an assembly etc. Also, the `Linker Description file` has an identical format across Android and iOS.

*Note*: Option 2 and 3 will only increase your app size a small amount, as it will ensure that all of the Autofac assembly is included in your app package, while all other assemblies not specified as part of 2 or 3 will continue to be linked.

I assume that the needs for one of these work-arounds is an indication that Autofac is currently not linker safe.

Comment: If I am not wrong it has been linker unsafe for more than 3 releases

Comment: May I ask something?  Documentation says, that you have to specify in linkskip assembly name without extension. But assembly name includes also version number, for example `Autofac.6.4.0`. It is not necessary too?